# How to swap(with yum) two rpms on fly?

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rpm, iproute2

I'm trying to install MPTCP(Multi-Path TCP) enabled kernel and tools on a CentOS7 box according to [the installation doc](https://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/RPM).
It needs 3 rpm packages to be installed.
I encounter a trouble when I installing iproute-mptcp_v0.94.

```
[root@c7builder tmp]# yum install iproute-mptcp_v0.94
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * epel: mirrors.yun-idc.com
 * extras: mirrors.aliyun.com
 * updates: mirrors.huaweicloud.com
Package iproute is obsoleted by iproute-tc, trying to install iproute-tc-mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package iproute-tc.x86_64 0:mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24 for package: iproute-tc-mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: iproute-tc-mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24.x86_64 (bintray-cpaasch-rpm)
           Requires: iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24
           Installed: iproute-4.11.0-14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               iproute(x86-64) = 4.11.0-14.el7
           Available: iproute-mptcp_v0.91-4.fc24.x86_64 (bintray-cpaasch-rpm)
               iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.91-4.fc24
           Available: iproute-mptcp_v0.92-4.fc24.x86_64 (bintray-cpaasch-rpm)
               iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.92-4.fc24
           Available: iproute-mptcp_v0.93-4.fc24.x86_64 (bintray-cpaasch-rpm)
               iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.93-4.fc24
           Available: iproute-mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24.x86_64 (bintray-cpaasch-rpm)
               iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24
           Available: iproute-4.11.0-14.el7_6.2.x86_64 (updates)
               iproute(x86-64) = 4.11.0-14.el7_6.2
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It looks like that "iproute-mptcp_v0.94" needs "iproute-tc-mptcp_v0.94" to be installed first, but "iproute-tc-mptcp_v0.94" either needs former!
I'm confused with this.
Would anybody like explain this for me?

Comment: Even though after "iproute" had been removed, it can not be installed.

Answer (score 1):

```
       Requires: iproute(x86-64) = mptcp_v0.94-5.fc24
       Installed: iproute-4.11.0-14.el7.x86_64
```

The version tags indicate this is a Fedora 24 package you are attempting to use on CentOS 7. This will not work.

Find an equivalent el7 package. Or compile it yourself against el7.